# Explode string with two different separators to create multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string:

> 01;Tommy;32;Coder&&02;Annie;20;Seller

I want it  like this:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=4)

  0 => string '01' (length=2)

  1 => string 'Tommy' (length=5)

  2 => int 42

  3 => string 'Coder' (length=5)  

1 => 
array (size=4)

  0 => string '02' (length=2)

  1 => string 'Annie' (length=5)

  2 => int 20

  3 => string 'Seller' (length=6)
```

Hope you can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if the datatypes will be matching (as I believe it's all in a string) but here's the code

```
 $myarray = array();
 foreach(explode("&&",$mystring) as $key=>$val)
 {
 $myarray[] = explode(";",$val);
 }
```

The explode command takes a string and turns it into an array based on a certain 'split key' which is && in your case
but since this is a dual array, I had to pass it through a foreach and another explode to solve.

Comment: what u calling explode() in foreach u need to put out of loop and just use variable in foreach

Comment: You don't need to explode out of the loop unless you are doing a large set.  It's slower sure, but 0.0003 vs 0.0004 seconds (outside vs inline) on a 2 element array isn't really doing any harm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861826/exploding-an-array-within-a-foreach-loop-parameter

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple. First you need to explode the string by `&&` and then traverse through array exploded by `&&`. And explode each element of an array by `;`.

Like this,

```
<?php

$str="01;Tommy;32;Coder&&02;Annie;20;Seller";

$array=explode("&&",$str);

foreach($array as $key=>$val){ 
    $array[$key]=explode(";",$val);
}
print_r($array);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/629507

Answer (score 3):

you should just have to split on '&&', then split the results by ';' to create your new two dimensional array:

```
// $string = '01;Tommy;32;Coder&&02;Annie;20;Seller';

// declare output
$output = [];

// create array of item strings
$itemarray = explode('&&',$string);
// loop through item strings
foreach($itemarray as $itemstring) {
  // create array of item values
  $subarray = explode(';',$itemstring);
  // cast age to int
  $subarray[2] = (int) $subarray[2]; // only useful for validation
  // push subarray onto output array
  $output[] = $subarray;
}

// $output = [['01','Tommy',32,'Coder'],['02','Annie',20,'Seller']];
```

keep in mind that since php variables are not typed, casting of strings to ints or keeping ints as strings will only last depending on how the values are used, however variable type casting can help validate data and keep the wrong kind of values out of your objects.

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is another appropach of solving this problem. Here I used `array_map()` with anonymous function:

```
$string = '01;Tommy;32;Coder&&02;Annie;20;Seller';

$result = array_map(function($value){return explode(';',$value);}, explode('&&', $string));
```