# Using GROUP_CONCAT in while loop to output multiple database entries by same user in one row

Tags: php, mysql

Would like to use GROUP_CONCAT in order to retrieve database info (images) from a userid with multiple image entries. These images are in the form of a file path. Would then like to have the images output in a single row per userid.

After extensive research on the matter, I find simple examples of what is needed, but I get lost with the query I currently have in place.

Here is my code as of now:

```
<table>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>High School</th>
                <th class="thLargest">Colleges</th>
            </table>
            <table>
                    <?php
                        session_start();

                        $conn = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");


                        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                        }

                        $sql = "SELECT college.id, college.title, GROUP_CONCAT(college.image) AS cImage, users.profileImage, users.fname, users.lname, users.level AS ulevel, users.city, users.state, users.highschool, users.primarysport, usercollege.id, usercollege.collegeid 
                                FROM college, users, usercollege 
                                WHERE usercollege.collegeid = college.id AND usercollege.userid = users.id 
                                ORDER BY usercollege.createdate ASC";


                        if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


                                if ($row['status'] == null) {
                                    echo "";
                                }

                                if ($row['ulevel'] == "A Profile") {
                                    echo '<tr>' .
                                            '<td class="small">' . '<a href="http://www.example.com/aprofile.php?user="'.$row["username"] . '>' . '<img src="'.$row['profileImage'].'" />' . '</a>' . '</td>' .
                                            '<td class="large">' . $row['fname']. ", " . $row['lname'] . '</td>' .
                                            '<td class="large">' . $row['city'] . ", " . $row['state'] . '</td>' .
                                            '<td class="large">' . $row['highschool'] . " (" . $row['primarysport'] . ") " . '</td>' .
                                            '<td class="largest">' .
                                                '<div class="Limage">' . '<img src="images/colleges/'.$cImage.'"/>' . '</div>' . 
                                            '</td>' .
                                        '</tr>';
                                }

                            }


                        mysqli_free_result($result);
                        }

                        mysqli_close($conn);
                    ?>
            </table>
```

The image portion in question is `'<img src="images/colleges/'.$cImage.'"/>' . '</div>'`.

A user could have up to 10 entries of college images, so i'd like to display these images side by side, rather than displayed in a different row with the same userid.

In other words, I'd like to group multiple rows of user data from the database in a single row with no duplicate userid in the table.

I've read about exploding the cImage and using foreach as well, but that's where my lack of experience gets me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.profileImage
     , users.fname
     , users.lname
     , users.city
     , users.state
     , users.highschool
     , users.primarysport
     , group_concat(college.image) AS cImage
  FROM usercollege
    INNER JOIN users
      ON users.id = usercollege.userid
    INNER JOIN college
      ON college.id = usercollege.collegeid
  GROUP BY users.id
  ORDER BY usercollege.createdate ASC
```

AND

```
foreach( explode(',', $row['cImage']) as $img )
  echo '<div class="Limage">' . '<img src="images/colleges/'.$img.'"/>' . '</div>';
```

Comment: receiving a syntax error with foreach. any suggestions.

Comment: Should work as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861826/exploding-an-array-within-a-foreach-loop-parameter). Maybe you are missing a `;` before `foreach`.

Comment: I changed the sql query to be `"SELECT......ASC";` and that helped solve the syntax error with that. Should `foreach` require brackets?

Comment: i placed the `foreach` code between `'<td class="largest">'` div in the original code. That correct?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that each php instruction (as `echo`) must be terminated with a semicolon. In `foreach` curly brackets are not required since it has a single instruction.

Comment: so I think the syntax error is caused by the `'<td class="largest">' .` before entering the `foreach`. if the td class is changed to `'<td class="largest">';` the error is gone, however, that ruins the table output and nothing is returned from the database.

Comment: You need to change after my code one more concatenation operator `.` for a new `echo `.