# Necessary to store result of explode() before foreach loop?

Tags: php, loops, explode

Is it necessary to store the result of `explode()` if all it will be used for is a loop?

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Is there any reason not to call it directly within the loop? Will `explode()` be called once, or for every iteration?

```
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $data) as $line) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: i prefer clean code where each line does one thing. other people don't. it's up to you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exploding an array within a foreach loop parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861826/exploding-an-array-within-a-foreach-loop-parameter)

Comment: if you want to run some benchmarks you can use `microtime` to find out how much it hurts to do either option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`explode()` will only be called once inside your `foreach` loop, if you have a very big code, you will have two choices:

## 1. Optimization/Speed:

Each variable holds some bytes of the memory, so if you have a big web application, i suggest calling the `explode()` inside the `foreach`, but if your application isn't that big, i don't think it will hurt to allocate some bytes.

## 2. Cleaner code:

The second option, is a clean code, if you assign your `explode` to a variable, it will be useful for later uses, and it will also make it easier to debug.

I'd like also to recommend [this article](https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html) for more informations.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs sorry but i think i have mentioned that in the "cleaner code" point

Comment: You do - no doubt - I more mean, make it clearer that separating the variables also means you still have the string in tact :) but tbf I suppose it's a redundant point, will rm :)